# Can't get url's to show color

Tags: hyperref, color

I want to have url's with no background, but still a distinctive color so as to indicate that they are clickable. I am defining

```
   \documentclass[line, margin]{res}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
linkcolor=red,
citecolor=green,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=cyan
}
\begin{document}
\name{Myname}
\address{address...} 
\begin{resume}

\href{http://example.com}{Text}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Res file can be found here: [link](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls)

Comment: (1) always post full minumal examples, we cannot see your document class. (2) might it be related to `hidelinks`?

Comment: Just tested and it is related to `hidelinks`. I gather that the colors are related to the links, not the text.

Comment: @daleif I have posted a full minimal example.

Comment: See Andrews answer, adding `colorlinks` also works. The standard frame around the text is associated to the links which you have hidden. Also remember that as Andrew mentions, `res` is not a generally known class, so the MWE isn't that usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `res.cls` is...I guess that it is your own non-standard class file (oh, just saw the link in the OP's post...).

In any case, you just need to set `colorlinks=true` in hypersetup:

```
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=red,
citecolor=green,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=cyan
}
```

With this your MWE gives (after replacing the `res` document class with `report` and ignoring your `\name` macro...):

[image]

Comment: that was right!